# Plotting a 2-variable implicit function in MatLab WITHOUT fimplicit or ezplot

Tags: matlab

I've been tasked with plotting the implicit function x^2 + y^2 = 1 + 4.5sin^2(xy), and I am not allowed to use "implicit plotting functions" like fimplicit or ezplot.

I'm stuck with plot, polarplot and fzero and that's about it.

The instructions seem to hint at conversion to a polar function being the key, but after a couple of hours of trying, reading and googling I still have no clue as to how to do it.

Converting x and y to their polar forms still doesn't allow solving for r for all values of theta so I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can not use either contour, fimplicit or ezplot.

I understand that your teacher wants you to use the `implicit function theorem`. You can find it's definition [Implcit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

I think you should start with the `The circle example` in the wikipedia article.

Remember that you only need to solve this for a portion of the graph the rest is only symetry.

Your starting point should be (x=0, y=1) which is a solution.

Then you will find that

```
dy/dx = (2x+9ysin(xy)cos(xy))/(2y+9xsin(xy)cos(xy))
```

You recognize a simple ODE

solving it in the simplest manner is start from (x=0, y=1) (which is a solution), choose a step dx (0.01) then save all points from the algorithm

```
y <- y + (2x+9ysin(xy)cos(xy))/(2y+9xsin(xy)cos(xy))*dx  
x <- x + dx
```

until you ran into trouble (where the determinant of the jacobian wiil be 0)

**For hints I leave the plot :**

I believe your implicit function will give result when x is in [-3,3] and also for y.

so

```
[x,y]=meshgrid([-3:0.01:3],[-3:0.01:3])
z= x.^2 + y.^2 - 1.0 - 4.5.*sin(x.*y).^2
v = [0,0];
contour(x,y,z,v)
```

should give you something like

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately contour is one of the tools mentioned as a "forbidden shortcut". The full quote is "Note that no shortcuts are allowed, so for example, the tools fimplicit and contour may not be used in the completion of the task."

So I guess my question sort of boils down to "how do I do what fimplicit/ezplot/contour does without using those (or related) tools?". Is there any remotely easy way of accomplishing that?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think I know what this is about.

Answer (score -1):

```
theta = linspace(0, 2.*pi, 1000);

for i = 1:length(theta) % Want to check every angle in theta.

% asign x = r*cos(theta) and y = r*sin(theta. You want to set the equation 
% equal to 0.
f = @(r)1 + 4.5.*(sin(r.^2.*(cos(theta(i)) .*sin(theta(i))))).^2 - r.^2;

r(i) = fzero(f, 3); % Solves the equation. The value 3 is just an 
% approximation of r, set it to any number you like. It just can't be too high.

% Make the two coordinates x and y. Asign them to their polar coordinates 
% using r.
x(i) = r(i).*cos(theta(i)); 
y(i) = r(i).*sin(theta(i));
end

plot(x,y)
grid on
axis equal
axis([-4 4 -4 4])
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks